# Linked list that has a hash table of its object

Tags: c, algorithm, hash

Suppose I have a linked list of a directory folders as

```
Root --> Folder A
     --> Folder B
     --> Folder C
```

each folder has a hash table of key as its name and an object as its value.

If I have a token as a path like  Root.Folder A, how would I search for it using the hash table and the linked list ? Pseudo code is better please.

I made an O(N^2) solution using linkedlist search, but now I put a hash table of name and the object, to make the search using the token O(N).

Comment: It's really not clear what you are talking about. Firstly, the diagram you have shown is not a linked list. Secondly, what does it mean by a "value" of a folder? Folders/directories contain other files and directories. So it's really hard to make sense of what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Its not actually a folder, its just a representation. what If I have a hash table for each Folder, that contains the name of the folder and the folder object it self. If I have A token string Root.Folder A, how would I go from Root to Folder A using the hashtables